# Can Invoke-AzVMRunCommand run a script that already exists on the Target VM?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Can Invoke-AzVMRunCommand run a script that already exists on the Target VM?

The reason I ask, is I need to run a script that is already on the Target VM because I have found it is taking 60 seconds to download the script from my machine to the Target VM, then only 1 second for it to execute and complete the script.

This is a time sensitive operation, so to be able to trim away 60 seconds on multiple steps that uses Invoke-AzVmRunCommand would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the script that already exists in your target VM. Here's how you can call the script.

```
$ScriptToRun ="< Path to your script >\sample.ps1"
Out-File -InputObject $ScriptToRun -FilePath ScriptToRun.ps1 
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand  -ResourceGroupName $rgname -Name $vmname -CommandId 
'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath ScriptToRun.ps1  -Verbose
Remove-Item -Path ScriptToRun.ps1
```

Comment: So I still need to send a script down, meaning I do not reduce total time of the task because I still have to wait for that file to be downloaded from my local machine to the VM.

Comment: As per your original post , you are looking for a way to run a script that already exists in your VM. In that case, you can use the script in the answer. You have to assign the path of script in VM  to $ScriptToRun. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/zh-CN/caf8c11a-7823-4aef-b266-241eb257497b/invokeazurermvmruncommand-azure-automation-path-of-the-file-when-i-try-to-run-from-azure?forum=azureautomation

Comment: I have just tried it, and although it works, the execution time of Invoke-AzVMRunCommand is still 61 seconds, even though the script only takes 1 second to complete, any idea why that is?